# jquery-ui-dialog from iframe over parent document

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

i have few previously built pages that use jquery-ui-dialog and works fine.
now my requirement was to make a page with a iframe in it.
and this iframe is used to display those previously created pages.
in this case the dialogs from the iframe appears inside the iframe 
not over the parent document. how can i make the dialogs appear over
the parent document containing the iframe with minimum change?

thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967904/how-to-popup-a-dialog-in-another-frame-using-jquery-ui

Answer (score 1):

If your pages are on the same domain, you could call a function in the parent document from the iframe to display the dialog.

For example...

```
parent.ShowDialog("Hello World");
```

With a function in the parent that opens up the UI dialog using the supplied text.

Comment: Not sure that the parent selector will return the HTMLDocument object

Comment: From my iframe document I am calling
parent.showDialog("#dialogId");

in my parent page I have

function showDialog(dialogId){
    $(dialogId).dialog("open");
};

but it is neither working nor showing any error

Comment: did you try calling it without the 'parent.' part?
Anyways, if I'm not mistaken, the correct syntax for calling it this way should be:
$("iframe").parent().showDialog('id');

Comment: The function in the parent page is getting called.
When I am calling the function sending the id of dialog which is in the iframe document.
Now I am not able to call the dialog(“open”) on that element of the iframe from the parent function.

Comment: Please submit some code for reference, I'm not sure what you are saying and pretty damn confused right now.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, iframes always seem to cause problems... best to avoid them completely (I understand if this probably wasn't your choice).

The problem is the browser interprets the i-frame as a separate web page. Not sure, but you could try to define your dialog element (the HTML tags) outside the i-frame and try calling the event from the inside. 
Something like:

```
<html>
<div id="callme" style="display:none;">
...
your dialogstuff here
...
</div>

<iframe>
<!-- function that calls the dialog event here -->
</iframe>
</html>
```

It's worth a shot, I guess.

Comment: is there a way i can keep my dialog stuff in the iframe document... other wise i have to move all different dialogs to the parent page.