# How to popup a dialog in another frame using jquery-ui

Tags: jquery, dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I'm creating a small web page using jquery-ui-1.8 which is having a frameset and three frames.

```
<frameset id="mainFrame"cols="25%,*,25%"> 
    <frame  id="f1" src="test.php"></frame> 
    <frame id="f2" src="test2.php"/>
    <frame  />
</frameset>
```

Then I have added a button to test.php file which is loaded at the first frame (f1) and a div to test2.php which is loaded at the second frame.

```
<div id="testdiv"> this is test 2</div>
```

Then I need to pop up a jquery dialog from "testdiv" on the second frame (f2) when I click on the button in the f1.

I tried following solutions given at these threads.
[1] - [Display jquery dialog in parent window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958946/display-jquery-dialog-in-parent-window)

```
var $jParent = window.parent.jQuery.noConflict();
var dlg1 = $jParent('#testdiv');
dlg1.dialog();
```

and
[2] - [jQuery UI dialog display inside frame, from bookmarklet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188116/jquery-ui-dialog-display-inside-frame-from-bookmarklet)

```
var frame = window.frames[1];
var div = $(frame.document.getElementById("testdiv"));
div.html("My popup contents");
div.dialog();
```

But non of these pop ups the dialog within the second frame. Can some one please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just make test for this way, maybe this is not the best way but you can try it.
(Attention: don't forget to add the attribute -> name="f2" <- on iframe f2)

in test.php:

```
<button onclick="parent.f2.$('#testdiv').dialog('open');">test</button>
```

---

in test2.php:

```
<link type="text/css" href="jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   $( "#testdiv" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false
   });
});
</script>

<div id="testdiv"> hello world! </div>
```

Comment: Thanks bungdito, It works fine and you saved lots of my time. :)