# How to bring the jquery ui-dialog out of it's parent iframe

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jquery dialog inside a 100px X 100px size iframe. The dialog box is actually bigger than it's parent iframe. I need to bring the dialog box out of it's parent and show it on the center of the top window.

**jquery version:**

jquery-1.8.0.min.js, jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js

I searched in stackoverflow and other blogs. The only closest answer I got was from the following. But that doesn't work either.

[How to popup a dialog in another frame using jquery-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967904/how-to-popup-a-dialog-in-another-frame-using-jquery-ui)

Both the iframe content and the top window content are from the same domain. But I don't want to add custom code outside of the iframe because I want to use it as a generic component.

Any solutions?

Comment: Does the iframed content belong to the same website?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967904/how-to-popup-a-dialog-in-another-frame-using-jquery-ui

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? Answering your own question below would be really helpful for others (like me).